# Determine between default value and actual value in XML serialization

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

My problem is this. I have a serializable class that I added a new field to it of type `int`.
 Now, if I `desrialize` an older `xml` in which the new field doesn't appear it will get the `default` value `0`.
I have my own `default` value, let's say the value `3`, to set in case the field is not initialized.
Also the user can modify the value of the field.
But how can I know if its value is `0` because it wasn't in the file, and in this case I need to override it with `3`, or because it was in the file with the value `0`? And in this case I don't need to change it

Comment: Carry one more attribute value to find out default or not.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about it, but I tried to avoid another property in the xml. Guess there is no alternative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just set your default value in your class?  For example:

```
public class SerializableObject
{
    public SerializableObject()
    {
        ValueWithDefault = 3;
    }

    public int ValueWithDefault { get; set; }
}
```

Now, if you were to deserialize XML where the value was missing, `ValueWithDefault` would be set to `3`.  If you were to deserialize XML where the value was present, then `ValueWithDefault` would be set to that value.

The only other option is to implement `IXmlSerializable` yourself, but this isn't something you really want to do if you can avoid it.  There are sadly no 'hooks' into the `XmlSerializer` process, it's all-or-nothing.

Comment: Damn that was simple :(